# Assign a domain name to a website hosted in DMZ server

Tags: router, dns, website, wamp

This project is new for me

**Situation**:

I have a web site hosted on a web server in DMZ on a local network. I also have a domain name **mydomaine**. 
I can access the web server from internet with a public IP-address. I want to access it with an address like **mydomain.com/Myapp**, knowing that mydomaine.com already host a website.

I can do it but the address bar keep showing me the  **public IP-address** when I connect to it instead of **mydomaine.com/Myapp** .

PS: I'm working with wamp server

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but am I understanding correctly that mydomaine.com/Myapp does show you your website, but it redirects to the ip address? If so, you need to alter the configuration of your website.

Comment: You have to work with CNAME values on your hosting environment.

Comment: How have you configured WAMP to receive this domain? Publicly, a nameserver can only allow a domain to resolve to one A record. Configured with your DNS provider, you should be pointing the A record for mydomain.com to your public IP address.
Following this, if you prefer to make your local computer connect to the server directly over the LAN, you can modify the computer's hosts file to manually direct mydomain.com to the local IP address. Most modern consumer routers also provide a loopback such that packets from within the LAN destined for your router's public IP will just route internally.

Comment: Is your website built using WordPress? Because that would explain this quote easily